# Is it redundant to have the same field in two MongoDb indexes?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a MongoDB index with two fields:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 1}
```

Would it make this index redundant?

```
{"a": 1}
```

Comment: no. no. no. no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it make this index redundant?
>
> ```
> {"a": 1}
> ```

Yes. It's [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix). Even with these exact index definitions.

> If you have a collection that has both a compound index and an index on its prefix (e.g. `{ a: 1, b: 1 }` and `{ a: 1 }`), if neither index has a sparse or unique constraint, then you can remove the index on the prefix (e.g. `{ a: 1 }`). MongoDB will use the compound index in all of the situations that it would have used the prefix index.